# Select distinct in wrong order

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table, where I want to get the 3 individual ids with the most recent entries.

```
id |     date
70 | 06.03.2017 10:55
71 | 07.03.2017 23:23
72 | 07.03.2017 23:30
72 | 07.03.2017 23:30
72 | 07.03.2017 23:30
73 | 07.03.2017 23:49
73 | 07.03.2017 23:51 
70 | 08.03.2017 00:00
74 | 08.03.2017 00:05
70 | 08.03.2017 00:06
18 | 08.03.2017 00:08 (wanted)
70 | 08.03.2017 00:11 (wanted)
74 | 08.03.2017 00:15 (wanted)
```

I tried several options (subquery, group by, order), but none of them worked.

The latest I tried was:

```
  $preview_create = 'select id ' 
              . 'from ( '
              . 'select id from table '
              . 'order by date desc'
              . ') as sub '
              . 'group by id '
              . 'limit 3';
```

It did not work out, so I have no other idea what to do.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, get the latest date for each id, in other word, group by id:

```
select id, max(`date`) as `date`
from yourtable
group by id
```

Secondly, order by `date` fetched by above query, it means:

```
select id
from (
    select id, max(`date`) as `date`
    from yourtable
    group by id
) t
order by `date` desc
limit 3
```

See [**demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c7e430/1) in sqlfiddle.